# Parameter passed to java command while running JUnit test case

Tags: java, junit

I would like to understand the meaning of the following command,with regards to JUnit:

```
java junit.swingui.TestRunner MoneyTest
```

The above command opens up the result of the testcase in JUnit Swing GUI. Whats the meaning of passing junit.swingui.TestRunner to the java command as a parameter ?

Thank You

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're instructing the JRE to run the `junit.swingui.TestRunner` class and pass it the argument *MoneyTest*